# Wrong request is send

Tags: symfony, httprequest

I have a Symfony 3 project where I have the following process:

1. A controller is called from the browser
2. At some point, the controller is sending a request to API x
3. after that, the controller is sending another request to another controller as service

the problem is that the request received from the last controller is intended for the first controller.

the code request for step 3 is the following:

```
 $requestFwd = Request::createFromGlobals();
                $requestFwd->request->add([ 'related_entry_id' => $dataToSend["related_entry_id"] ]);

                // call internal controller
                $ApiService = $this->container->get('App\ApiBundle\Controller\APIRestController');
                $response = $ApiService->Notify($requestFwd);
```

Any ideas what is the problem?

CORS are enabled in the server (nginx)

Comment: the another controller is at same project?

Comment: Yes, it is the same project.

Comment: Please try to execute you controller as a subrequest as described in the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html

Comment: place the #sub-requests at end of your url

Comment: thanks that worked.